# Play Twitch stream on exoplayer android app

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, twitch

I'm trying to develop an Android application on Java which plays two Twitch streams on same time. I've decided to use Exoplayer because it has good video stream support.

I created this method which I call on onCreate method. This method works with .MP4 online files, but it doesn't work with any Twitch link

```
private void playVideo() {

    try {
        simpleExoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
        playerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);
        MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(twitch_link);
        simpleExoPlayer.addMediaItem(mediaItem);
        simpleExoPlayer.prepare();
        simpleExoPlayer.play();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a `twich_link` you're trying to play? Make sure it is in one of the supported formats: https://exoplayer.dev/supported-formats.html

Comment: I've tried normal link (the one you copy from browser) and this one: "twitch://open?stream=lcs";

Comment: I don't think expolayer understands the `twitch://` protocol

Comment: I already visited that link before but I don't understand very well which format should I use

Comment: I believe you will need a direct stream to the mp4/hls/whatever stream, rather than a link to the webpage/twitch URL. Also that's assuming it's not protected in any way